# Regex: Match password in MSSQL connection string, taking quote-wrapping into account

Tags: javascript, regex

I am dealing with MSSQL connection strings in different formats, and I need to be able to extract the password, whether or not it is wrapped in (single or double) quotes. I also need to ensure that, if the password contains quotes or semicolons, I am capturing the whole password, without the wrapping quotes. If there are multiple quotes at the start of the password, I need to capture all but the first one.

So far, I have constructed the following Regular Expression:

```regex
/(?<=Password=["']?).+?(?=["'];|["';]?$)/gim
```

This RegEx catches an unwrapped password (`...Password=foobar;... :: foobar`) BUT also catches the first quotemark in a wrapped password (`...Password="foobar";... :: "foobar`) or, if I remove the `?` in the lookbehind as follows, I capture the wrapped passwords correctly, but I miss unwrapped passwords.

```regex
/(?<=Password=["']).+?(?=["'];|["';]?$)/gim
```

Ideally, I'd like to accomplish this without additional Javascript. Question is tagged Javascript because that's the engine I'm using. I'm aware I could substring if the password starts with a quote, but the goal is to find a RegEx solution.

Here is a regexr with some sample test cases: https://regexr.com/4n2lt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is expected. You need `/Password=["']?(.*?)(?:["'];|["';]?$)/gim` and extract the contents of Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pi0i7f/2).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, would you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite width lookbehind is actually works like this and is usually used like this: to make sure there is some specific pattern **not immediately before** the required pattern.

Thus, *the optional pattern(s) at the end of a lookbehind always turn up in the consumed match.*

You should use a consuming pattern instead:

```
/Password=["']?(.*?)(?:["'];|["';]?$)/gim
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pi0i7f/2), extract Group 1 value.